# Why doesn't my React getDOMNode().textContent javascript string equal a string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react application, I'm trying to test a string that I output to the DOM against my expected output.

My `outputString` is pulled using `getDOMNode()`:

```
var test = attendingNode.getDOMNode().textContent; 
// Returns "1 person attending:"
```

The problem is, it It throws the following results. Why doesn't the output of the `getDOMNode().textContent` equal the equivalent string? How do I make the output work so that I can test against the string that I'm expecting? Thanks!

```
> test
> "1 person attending:"
> test == "1 person attending:"
> false
> test.constructor
> function String() { [native code] }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a difference in the characters in the white space between `1` and `person`. See:

```
> ["1 p".charCodeAt(1), "1 p".charCodeAt(1)]
[160, 32]
```

160 (`A0`) is the non-breaking space whereas 32 (`20`) is the normal space character. You should make this explicit by changing the expected string to `"1\u00A0person attending:"`. See that:

```
> "1 person attending:" == "1\u00A0person attending:"
true
```